# Arithmetic element by element difference between 2 collections using Java Generics

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, array-difference

Say we got 2 ordered collections of numbers. We want to compute the arithmetic difference element by element.
I think we need to use List of Number in order to model the idea of 'ordered collection of numbers'.
The problem is that the arithmetic difference (a banal '-' like in 3-2) is not defined for Number.
I can cast everything to Double, but I'd rather prefer a clean solution.

```
public static <E extends Number> List<E> listDifferenceElementByElement(List<E> minuend, List<E> subtrahend) throws Exception {
    if (minuend.size() != subtrahend.size()) {
        throw new Exception("Collections must have the same size"); //TODO: better exception handling
    }
    List<E> difference = new ArrayList<E>();
    int i = 0;
    for (E currMinuend : minuend) {
        difference.add(currMinuend-subtrahend.get(i)); //error: The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) E, E
        i++;
    }
    return difference;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need the type to generic? What if you made `E` a `Double` instead?

Comment: Let's say I want something which can work with any numeric type (Integer, Float, Double, ...) and possibly return the same type

Comment: As an exercise, you can't do it in a simple manner. In reality it's very useful as there is not much to be gained if you had such a  feature.  If you care about performance you might use a `long[]` or `double[]` instead.  This is what is usually used in maths libraries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arithmetic operations with Java Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873215/arithmetic-operations-with-java-generics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Number` does not provide any `subtract` method, you can't do it simply. The alternatives I can think of are:

1. use the provided `doubleValue()` method, and return a `double`, but you could lose precision if the lists contain BigDecimal for example.
2. have one method per available `Number` subclass, but it could create a lot of duplicated code...
3. restrict the type to whatever makes sense (say double if precision does not matter too much or BigDecimal if it does), which is a subcase of (2).

Option 2 could be implemented like by replacing `difference.add(currMinuend-subtrahend.get(i));` by `difference.add(subtract(currMinuend, subtrahend.get(i)));`

Then it's only a matter of writing 10 `subtract` methods:

```
private static int subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
private static double subtract(double a, double b) { return a - b; }
private static BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) { return a.subtract(b); }
```

etc.

Comment: BigDecimal is the way to go here

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup That's one way to do it indeed.

Comment: I somehow thought about the same possible strategies, but I think there is a better solution probably.
Imagine I can inspect at runtime the type of the elements in minuend: if they are Integer or Double or so I can use the arithmetic operator '-' and return a Set of Integer or Double or so.
Right?

Comment: @Paolo You could do that, which would in the end boil down to the second option: one method per type.

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup and assylias
Yes, I will go for that, one method per type.
Btw in Python I would have done it much easier (when I first moved from Java to Python I was always saying that I would have done it much easier in Java. Now that I moved back, I'm saying the opposite... lol!!)

Comment: @Paolo you could simply implement it by creating one `subtract` method per type, which is going to be a one line method, and call it from your generic method. That should not take very long to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with generics, arrays, etc. Java doesn't allow operator overloading, so you cannot subtract 2 numbers with `-`, and the `Number` class doesn't define any methods for numeric operations. It can't because it might be operating on different subclasses (e.g. Integer.subtract(Double)) which would make defining the return type impossible.

You will need to use intrinsic types or `BigDecimal` (or similar) here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with many arithmetic type, you can set your list as a generic list, then add the handler when you want to find the difference between them. The handler check if the type is instance of Double, Integer, or anything you want. Based on each type, you could compute the difference.