# airthmetic operation with generic concept in java

Tags: java

i m trying to calculate the salary in abstract class(in which i m implementing one interface)
and trying to extend that abstract class into another class and adding some incentive to that salary but when i m calcuting then it is showing '+' opertor is underifned with generic type

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class SalaryInfo<T, V extends Number> implements info<T, V> {
   T hours;
   T rate;
   T pay;

   public void calculatePay(T hours, T rate) {
      pay = hours * rate;
      // Do your math with Integer class methods help
   }

   // return new Double(hours.doubleValue() * rate.doubleValue());
   // System.out.println("pay is b :" +pay);
   public void show() {
      System.out.println("post is :");
   }
}
```

package com.demo;

```
public interface info<T,V>  
{
    public void calculatePay(T hours, T rate);
    public void perinfo(V empid,T empname );
    public void display();

}
```

Comment: Please show the code that is causing the error. Please compact your code a little so it's easier to read. Judicious use of whitespace helps improve your code's readability, but too much whitespace reduces readability. The more readable the code, the better answers you'll likely get. Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked several times. You can't use arithmetic operations with classes just with primitive types.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels TL;DR OP wants to use `Number a; Number b; return a + b;` and other arithmetic operations for these objects.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I'm sure you're correct, but regardless, he should post the offending code. It should be fairly obvious that if one asks a question about code that's causing a compilation error, that one should post the offending code and indicate which line it is. I'm just trying to encourage him to ask a complete question is all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree with you about the format of the question :). Just to note, the problem is in this line: `pay= hours * rate;`

Comment: Have you tried `<T extends Number, V extends Number>` (in both `info` and `SalaryInfo`)?

Comment: @EmilLundberg: that won't work either. Test it yourself and you'll see.

Comment: Not possible due to erasure.  

See [this SO][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873215/arithmetic-operations-with-java-generics

Comment: Ah. I'll admit I was too lazy to try it, just wanted to throw the idea out there. :>

Comment: @Ayman: no, type erasure is not the cause of this. If you used `T extends Double` this could possibly work (but won't for other reasons). It's simply because Number does not allow use of math operators.

Comment: If you use Double, then you are autoboxing and converting everything to double.  In which case, why bother with Numbers and Type at all?

Comment: @Ayman: I agree. I'm just pointing out that type erasure isn't the culprit here.

Comment: No it is also not wprking <T extends Number, V extends Number> and can u tell me the correct syntax how to rite this bcoz whn i m typung in interfacce its correct and still in class when i m typing like  this still its correct but when i m completing the class line implements info<T extends Number, V extends Number> it is showing error in this line why it is like that?

Comment: so u guyz asking me to print the full code actully it is program in which i m using abstract class,inheritance inner class concept so many things those thngs are wrking nw i want to make generalize my program so i want generic concept to introduce it and one part i have done through genric i can pass the name and emp id nw i want to calculate emp salary so plz help me tomorrow i have to show this program so plz guyzzz

Comment: Please consider using punctuation and correct spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach is wrong, it has been mentioned that you cannot do math with generics as the math operators are not defined for the autoboxing classes (Integer, Double etc). If your pays never exceed the maximum for doubles, which is something along `10^308` you can simply store the payrate in doubles and the rest of the interface implementation will be as before.

```
public interface info<T, V> {
public void calculatePay(double hours, double rate);

public void perinfo(V empid, T empname);

public void display();

}
```

With implementation

```
public class SalaryInfo<T extends Number, V extends Number> implements
    info<T, V> {

double hours, rate, pay;

@Override
public void perinfo(V empid, T empname) {

}

@Override
public void display() {

}

@Override
public void calculatePay(double hours, double rate) {
    pay = hours * rate;
}

public void show() {
    System.out.println(pay);
}

}
```

Comment: thnks a lot sir but suppose if i want to use generic way to provide the values in salary calculation for that wat shuld i do ...plz tell me .....

Comment: and u r writing T in perinfo so at run time it is showing some string and number related prblm bcoz as empname i m passing sm name to so it is shwoing sm string type error...

Comment: hey .... anybody tell me solution regarding this prblm

Comment: <T, V extends Number> then. You should really read up on generics a bit before attempting to use it like this ;)