# Add Comparable interface to SimpleEntry

Tags: java, generics

I tried to add interface Comparable to class SimpleEntry by subclass it. Because SimpleEntry is a generic type, I used this:

```
public class SimpleEntryComparable<K, V> extends SimpleEntry<K, V> implements
        Comparable<T> {

    public SimpleEntryComparable(K arg0, V arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

And eclipse complained "T cannot be resolved to a type".
I'm confused about subclass a generic class and add interfaces... anyone can tell me something about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[chrylis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678776/697449) is correct. Below it I see you have this comment:

> But in compareTo(), I want to "return o.getKey() - this.getKey();"

Based on this comment, it sounds like you want the following:

```
public class SimpleEntryComparable<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
extends SimpleEntry<K, V>
implements Comparable<SimpleEntryComparable<K, V>> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final SimpleEntryComparable<K, V> other) {
        return getKey().compareTo(other.getKey());
    }
}
```

This ensures that `K` is comparable to itself (or some super-type of itself), so that your code can delegate to that type's `compareTo` implementation. This is the only way to do generic comparisons of reference types - [as chrylis points out,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678762/add-comparable-interface-to-simpleentry#comment27512906_18678776) arithmetic operations [are only supported for primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873215/arithmetic-operations-with-java-generics).

Answer (score 2):

The `<T>` on `Comparable` tells the compiler what type the class can be compared to. In your case, if you want to be able to compare to other `SimpleEntryComparable`s, you just need `implements Comparable<SimpleEntryComparable<K,V>>` (and `compareTo`, of course!).

Comment: Thank you. But in compareTo(), I want to "return o.getKey() - this.getKey();". However, the type of Key/Value are generic and this statement just failed. What shall I do?

Comment: You can't ever subtract objects in Java, only primitives. If you're trying to make your entries `Comparable`, you have to be able to describe the order they should go in. If you can't, then instead of a `SimpleEntryComparable`, you should just write a `Comparator<SimpleEntry<K,V>>`.