# Bounded Types in java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I am unable to understand why this code is not compiling...

```
public class Room {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] ar = {1.1,2.23,3.56,4.23,5.90,6.88,7.99,8.09,9.88,10.99};
        Average<Double> tt = new Average<>(ar);
        tt.summ();
    }
}

class Average<T extends Double> {
    T[] arr;
    T sum;
    Average(T[] num) {
        arr = num;
    }

    void summ() {
        for (T i : arr) {
            sum = sum + i;//Shows incompatible types
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler error states:

> Error on Room.java, line 18:
>
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to T

Can somebody please explain why this code is not compiling??

Comment: *String args[]* Please write the brackets on the type, not the variable, since it belongs to the type. Furthermore, please include the compilation error.

Comment: @Turing85 - No thats not the solution...still not compiling.

Comment: You have not even included the error..

Comment: @RajMalhotra I know that it is not the solution. It is just a comment on your coding style. To solve your problem, we need the actual compilation error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I do arithmetic operations on the Number baseclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873215/can-i-do-arithmetic-operations-on-the-number-baseclass)

Comment: Error: Incompatible types in the line sum=sum+i

Answer (score 5):

Eran is right; `java.lang.Double` is `final`, so it makes no sense to have a type parameter `T extends Double`. The only possible type that satiesfies this is `Double` itself, so you can just as well remove the type parameter and just use `Double` directly (or better yet: the primitive type `double`).

The reason why your code doesn't compile is because you are trying to use the `+` operator on objects of type `T`.

The Java compiler is not so smart that it notices that `T` can only be `Double`, so that it automatically can convert (by auto-unboxing and -boxing) the value to a `double` to do the calculation.

Maybe you come from a C++ background and you've used C++ templates. Java generics do not work in the same way as C++ templates; generic types in Java are not templates from which code is generated.

Comment: "*so that it automatically can convert (by auto-unboxing and -boxing) the value to a double to do the calculation.*" - **this** is the actual answer to the actual question

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in this generic type parameter having this bound :

```
class Average<T extends Double>
```

since Double is final and can have no sub-types.

Therefore you might as well remove the generic type parameter T and replace T with Double everywhere.

Comment: In this case, OP might want to substitute `T` with `double` instead of `Double`, which gets rid of the compilation error.

Comment: @Eran,but why the code is not compiling?..Even if I write<T extends Number>,then also its showing compilation error

Comment: @Codebender The OP's code gives a compilation error - `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to T` on the line `sum=sum+i;`

Comment: if we could teach java compiler which type to use during compilation then it could work

Comment: @RajMalhotra read the "possible duplicate of..." comment given by Andy Brown. This should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what exactly your code should archive, I am not sure about the correctness of this answer, but a quick fix (at least to avoid syntax error) is to substitute the line:

```
T sum;
```

with:

```
double sum;
```

With this, your output is the incremental sum of all the double, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is arithmetic operator to use with numbers or strings,  but it cant be used with `Object` type. If you want to use `+` operator both operand should have the same type.

```
class Average<T extends Double> {
  T[] arr;
  double sum = 0;
  Average(T[] num) {
    arr = num;
  }

  void summ() {
    for (T i : arr) {
      sum += (Double)i;//Shows incompatible types
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```