# I want to add generic type numbers

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I have a simple class called Employee.

```
public class Employee<T extends Number> {
    private final String id; 
    private final String name;
    private final T salary; //generic type salary

    public Employee(String id,String name,T salary){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public T getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

}
```

Here using reduction, i am able to add Double type. But i need generic type addition. The values in the salary can be either Double or Integer. So is there any way to use provide any flexibility so that i can add any Sub type of Number.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creates employee list and three employees in it
        List < Employee > employees = new LinkedList < > ();
        employees.add(new Employee("E001", "John", 30000.00));
        employees.add(new Employee("E002", "Mark", 45000.00));
        employees.add(new Employee("E003", "Tony", 55000.00));
        employees.stream().map(Employee::getSalary).reduce(0, (a, b) -> {
        //only able to add double type values, but i need any sub type of number
                return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
            });
    }



Please help me.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I do arithmetic operations on the Number baseclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873215/can-i-do-arithmetic-operations-on-the-number-baseclass)

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I need to know one way, so that i am able to add either integer or double.  

employees.stream().map(Employee::getSalary).reduce(0, (a, b) -> {
        //only able to add double type values, but i need any sub type of number
                return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
            });

Here, i have bounded the addition of double. I need to know that is there any way so that i can eliminate this bound and use any number type addition.

Comment: No sane programmer would use `double` values for monetary values. Likewise, the idea of abstracting the actual type of both, storage and calculations, of salaries makes no sense. It causes problems for no benefit.

Comment: Generifying over numbers never, ever goes well.  Never.  Pick one number type for the whole program and stick with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to first add the correct generic type arguments in your variable declarations:

```
List<Employee<Double>> employees = new LinkedList<>(); // you need to add "<>"s here
employees.add(new Employee<>("E001", "John", 30000.00));
employees.add(new Employee<>("E002", "Mark", 45000.00));
employees.add(new Employee<>("E003", "Tony", 55000.00));
```

Then, this will return a `double` which is convertible to `Number`, and `Number` can be converted to `int`, `float`, `short` etc:

```
Number num = employees.stream().map(Employee::getSalary).reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> {
        return a + b;
});
```

Alternatively, just get rid of the generics. Instead of using `T`, just use `Number` as the type of salary.

```
class Employee {
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Number salary; //generic type salary

    public Employee(String id,String name,Number salary){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Number getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

}
```

Comment: If i take the first approach i.e

Comment: ' List<Employee<Number>> employees = new LinkedList<>();
        employees.add(new Employee("E001", "John", 30000.00));
        employees.add(new Employee("E002", "Mark", 45000.00));
        employees.add(new Employee("E003", "Tony", 55000.00));
        Number num = employees.stream().map(Employee::getSalary).reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> {
            return a + b;
        });'

It gives me error..

bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  Number
  second type: Number

Comment: Sorry, you have specified, Employee<Double>, Yes Number class does not have addition operation. But i need to know that can i use if -else statement  in the accumulator section in the reduce() method so that i can check the instance type for a and b based upon that i can apply addition to the correct type. like  return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue(); 

Please tell me is there any trick or way available in Java or not.

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal No you don't do that. You don't check what specific type of `Number` it is. That is the whole point of using generics. You should just return a `double` and then assign that to a variable of type `Number`. After that, you can convert the `Number` to other types using `intValue()`, `shortValue()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy out of this... As the compiler can't do addition via `+` on two `Number`s. You could of course use `a cast` here. The deeper problems might arise when an Employee has salary of type `Double`, but *another* of type `Long` for example, in which case casts are going to get pretty nasty.

One approach if you are ok with returning a `BigDecimal` is this:

```
  BigDecimal r = employees.stream().map(Employee::getSalary)
            .map(n -> new BigDecimal(n.toString()))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (left, right) -> {
                return new BigDecimal(left.toString()).add(new BigDecimal(right.toString()));
            });
```